# Unexpected behaviour for isKindOfClass: on NSManagedSubclasses created by mogenerator

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmanagedobject, objective-c-runtime, mogenerator

I have an entity in my object model called Book whose class attribute is `XYZBook`. Mogenerator creates 2 classes:

- `_XYZBook`
- `XYZBook`, which inherits from `_XYZBook`.

So far so good.

If I create an instance on `XYZBook`:

```
XYZBook *b = [XYZBook insertInManagedObjectContext:context];
```

Sending `class` to b, returns `XYZBook` as expected.

```
[b class] --> XYZBook
```

However, sending `isMemberOfClass:[XYZBook class]` returns NO!!!

```
[b isMemberOfClass:[XYZBook class]] --> NO
```

It only returns `YES` if I use the `_XYZBook` super class:

```
[b isMemberOfClass:[_XYZBook class]] --> YES
```

So, what on Earth is going on????

BTW, I create these clases using a custom base class (with the --base-class option for mogenerator). Just in case it has anything to do with this...

Comment: As a sanity check, split the line up. Assign the result of `isMemberOfClass:` to a `BOOL` variable. Confirm this is `YES`. Then pass the `BOOL` variable to `XCTAssertTrue`.

Comment: Print `[[strs objectAtIndex:0] class]` and you will see, that it's not exact `NSString`. May be `isKindOfClass` can suit you better.

Comment: @Cy-4AH I tried what you suggested and found out the real problem. The example code was went to isolate the real problem (which is related to NSManagedObject subclasses created by mogenerator. I will completely rewrite the question.

Comment: What are the complete interface definitions for the two classes?